# How to import live video stream and capture one frame

Tags: c#, video-streaming, video-capture

How would I go about capturing one frame from a feed of video from a webcam or video capture card in C#?  I want to display the live feed and have a method that takes one frame and saves it to a remote server either via FTP or over a shared network path.

Comment: I implemented it on node.js. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099513/capture-thumbnail-whilte-downloading-youtube-video if you're interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use OpenCV. If you search on StackOverflow you'll find a lot of source on how to do that.

There's even .NET wrappers for OpenCV like [opencvdotnet](http://code.google.com/p/opencvdotnet/) and [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).

You will probably end up using a few functions from the library, such as cvCaptureFromCAM() and cvQueryFrame().

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to streaming live video, then  you can capture the live video stream just click on button by this code:

```
private Capture capture = null;

private void btnStart_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if ( capture == null )
                    throw new ApplicationException( "Please select a video and/or audio device." );
                if ( !capture.Cued )
                    capture.Filename = txtFilename.Text;
                capture.Start();
                btnCue.Enabled = false;
                btnStart.Enabled = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show( ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.ToString() );
            }
        }
```